# Check for Internet connection?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm stuck here. I had a problem of checking the form if submitted successfully and data is inserted. I will check the data in a mysql query whether data is inserted or not by using an `if` condition:

```
$sql_query = mysql_query("Insert") or die(mysql_error());    

if($sql_query){ 
    echo "1";
}else{
    echo "0";
}
```

Now the problem is, if the Internet connection is gone when submitting the form, then how do I handle the submitted data? I don't want to refill or resubmit the form whenever the internet connection is gone.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: If the internet connection is gone then your server isn't going to receive anything, so there's nothing to handle.

Comment: @MarkParnell yeah, but the client could still do some handling locally

Answer (score 1):

You can use formData plugin to save form data.

http://fishcantwhistle.com/jquery-plugin-saveform/

It saves form data in cookies, as user types it. So if internet connection is lost, and user comes back to your site, he still sees all his filled form.

Download it from:

http://fcw.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/saveForm.zip

include js file in your html and put `<script>jQuery.saveForm();</script>` somewhere. Note that jQuery is pre req for this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If your query will successfully run than not to worry about that. And for your query successfully inserted you can check with get auto increment id get.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

```
$sql_query=mysql_query("Your Insert query") or die(mysql_error());
$result_id = mysql_insert_id();
if($result_id)
{
   echo '1';
}
else
{
  echo '0';
}
```

Comment: yea..what u said is right...my problem is if internet connection is gone when submitting the form ...i dnt want resubmit the form..i want to handle the submitted data even if net connection is gone..

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML5 Local Storage API provides the ability to persist named
>   key/value pairs locally within a users browser. This means that the
>   data stored in Local Storage is still there even if a user closes
>   their browser, deletes their cookies or turns off their
>   machine/device. For a more detailed explanation of HTML5 Local
>   Storage.

Store data in Browser using HTML5 `LocalStorage`

You need to do a little brainstorming for `HTML5 Web Storage`

Check this link - [HTML5 Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Example - http://www.simonbingham.me.uk/index.cfm/main/post/uuid/using-html5-local-storage-and-jquery-to-persist-form-data-47

Comment: i checked this one...but client side people use only internet explorer...  :(

Comment: @Chethi IE8 supports LocalStorage

Comment: @Chethi IE 8.0+ support this feature

Comment: @jan Dvorak ...ya ryt...but most of the client people dnt know how to upgrade bowser.. :(

Comment: @Chethi You need to understand there is always a limitation..you can pop up a message that prompts user to use upgraded version for better site functionality....and one thing more dont dive into HTML5 for these CAVE people

Comment: @swapnesh..ya...ur ryt..i explained same thing to my boss...but he couldn't understand..he wants to do something to handle..im trying... trying...

Comment: @Chethi Just ask ur boss then which technology should i search in then ?? and let me know his suggestion ;) I more thing (just came in mind..let me update my answer)